# Delete empty dataframes from a list with dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

This is a list of dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
data=[pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],columns=['a']),pd.DataFrame([]),pd.DataFrame([]),
pd.DataFrame([3,4,5,6,7],columns=['a'])]
```

I am trying to delete the empty dataframes from the above list that contains dataframes.

Here is what I have tried:

```
for i in data:
    del i.empty()
data
```

which gives:

```
File "<ipython-input-33-d07b32efe793>", line 2
    del i.empty()
        ^ SyntaxError: cannot delete function call
```

**Important**:It needs to store them in the `data` variable as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ca use `filter`

```
data = list(filter(lambda df: not df.empty, data))
```

or **list comprehension**

```
data = [df for df in data if not df.empty]
```

---

```
print(data)

[   a
0  1
1  2
2  3,    a
0  3
1  4
2  5
3  6
4  7]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=['a']), pd.DataFrame([]),
        pd.DataFrame([]),
        pd.DataFrame([3, 4, 5, 6, 7], columns=['a'])]

for i in range(len(data)-1, 0, -1):
    if data[i].empty:
        del data[i]

print(data)
```

The problem with your code is that `df.empty` returns True or False, While what you want to do is delete the item `i` if `i.empty()` returned True.

Please noted that in the range we use a reversed range in order to avoid getting list item `out of range` error.

Comment: gives this: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`

Comment: If you print the `data` variable afterwards, nothing has changed in the `data` list. It has kept the empty dataframes.

Comment: @user14305909 updated last time, tested this and it works

Comment: y think this is unnecesary, you don't need range here

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
[i for i in data if len(i)>0]
```

Output:

```
[   a
0  1
1  2
2  3,    a
0  3
1  4
2  5
3  6
4  7]
```

Comment: The correct way is `DataFrame.empty` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html